# Excel: Only count unique cells from Countif

Tags: excel, count, unique

Is there a way to only count unique cells from the `CountIF` function?

I have a table that is like:
[image]

My countif function is `=COUNTIF(A1:A6,">2")` to count all the cells that are >2. This returns `4` but it counts the number 3 twice. Is there a way to make it only count the unique values and have it return 3?

Comment: I think the best solution would be vba, or maybe a macro. there might be a complicated way doing it using VLookUp, but cant think how right now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `FREQUENCY` function, like this:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A6>2,A1:A6),A1:A6),1))`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

See screenshot:

You could also use a "non-array" version along similar lines to Brockr22's suggestion, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6>2)/COUNTIF(A1:A6,A1:A6&""))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array formula
This link explains how to do so: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-unique-values.html